# Proving a curve is generalized helix

Tags: differential-geometry

Curve is defined in a following way $\alpha(t)=(2t,\ln t,t^2)$. I want to prove that it is generalized helix. I tried parametrizing through arc length but it got messy fast. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* (ever) reparametrize by arclength. Just use the chain rule along with the Frenet formulas. You can see various examples in, for instance, [my text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately that link is not working for me.

Comment: UGA internet connectivity issues repaired. Link works fine now.